# RTS Style Game With Client-Side Prediction

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, game-development

So, I am currently working on an RTS-like multiplayer game. Units are not controllable by players (they attack-move to a location automatically).

I decided not to go full lockstep but instead do a state-based / prediction hybrid. The game is fully simulated on the client with a state packet for every unit distributed only once per second (Position, health etc.). I've read that this is quite a common method of doing things these days but i'm having major issues with it. One clear problem is with health syncing. Damage is dealt locally on every client machine and corrected via the state packet. This results in issues similar to this:

- Projectile hits a unit on a client machine, taking him from 100 health down to 50.
- Client only then receives a state packet from the server saying he is on 100 health which spikes it back up.

Of course he will receive another corrective packet later on taking him back down to 50 but this causes really bad visual spikes. This issue gets even worse if you consider the impact of ability damage and such.

Have I completely misunderstood what is required to create a client-predicted game or do I just need to treat every variable on a case-by-case basis? (I.E. Put in silly hacks to make the health not look bad).

Answer (score 0):

I would've posted this on [Game Dev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/), as is is primarily a "what can I do?" kind of question but here's fine as there are some technical aspects.

As to your issue, what I'd do is:

## Don't let the client predictive sim actually deal damage to units.

Or if you do, have the damage be 1/4 to 1/10th of what it actually is and visually display a value that is `Math.min(Math.max(sim_hp, 5%), last_packet_hp)`, which prevents jumps up, but allows the server to correct downwards (and the client predictive damage acts as a visually pleasing "animation" between the last and current values). The client is also not allowed to reduce a unit's HP below 5% unless it actually dies on the server. Any discrepancies observable at this point can be easily ignored by players (as players are well acquainted with network lag and packet loss).